# RabbitMQ Shovels based on number of messages in a queue

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there a way to configure a shovel, to only start shoveling, if the numbers of messages in a queue exceeds a certain number of messages.

Comment: Can you describe in more details what you want to do?

Comment: Wanted to get other rabbitmq nodes to help with the load of other nodes. Shovels are not the right thing to use. Have switched to federeated queue.